# Converting PDF portfolios to plain text (pdftotext?)

Tags: pdf

I am trying to convert a large number of PDFs (~15000) to plain text using pdftotext.  This is working pretty well except for a few of the PDFs (~600) which, I guess, are "PDF portfolios."

When I run these PDFs through pdftotext, it just outputs:

> For the best experience, open this PDF portfolio in Acrobat 9 or Adobe
>   Reader 9, or later. Get Adobe Reader Now!

If I do open these PDFs in Adobe Reader, they look like two or more PDFs inside a single file.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?  Is there any tool I can use to convert these PDFs automatically? (Either directly to text or at least to regular PDFs that pdftotext can then understand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html).

It has a utility `pdfdetach` which can extract the files from a Pdf portfolio.

```
pdfdetach -saveall your_pdf_portfolio.pdf
```

I don't know which `pdftotext` you are using, but Xpdf also has its own `pdftotext`.